# zssh can't start and shows "out of pty's" when start

Tags: linux, centos, pty

In CentOS 6.5, yum install zssh, but when I execute zssh, it gives an error showing: out of pty's.

What does this mean? How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the list of used `ptys` with

```
ls /dev/pts
```

The maximum number of `ptys` is given by

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/pty/max
```

That value can be configured in

```
/etc/sysctl.conf
```

(see `man pty`)

Note that some versions of the kernel were [buggy](https://lkml.org/lkml/2009/11/5/370).

The `ptys`, or [pseudo terminals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal)  are the 'channels' through which a process interacts with the user console (keyboard and screen)

Comment: the kernel is 2.6.32-431.17.1, /dev/pts/ has only 9 files, /proc/sys/kernal/pty/max is 4096. is this buggy?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some weird library mismatch bug that cropps up in some binary distributions. See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=769366. Has not been tracked down, but a simple recompile seems to be a workaround.